# JQuery UI datepicker not showing from input field, but only from around it

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have an input field to which I added a datepicker.
For some reason, when I click the input field the datepicker won't open, but if I click around it, the datepicker opens and fills in the data in the field.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <label for="video_due_date">Birthday Date</label>
  <div class="text">
    <input id="video_due_date" name="video[due_date]" size="30" type="text" value="2011-12-24 13:51:58 UTC" />                                                      
  </div>                                
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.sign-form .row .text,
.sign-form .place-holder{
    float:left;
    background:url(../images-2/sprite-form.gif) no-repeat 0 -44px;
    position:relative;
    height:38px;
}
```

And this is the code of the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#video_due_date').datepicker({minDate: 0,
                                   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd     00:00:00'
                                  });
});
</script>
```

Have you got any idea what could cause this problem, and what should I change in order to have the datepicker open from within the field and not from the area around it?

Thanks,
Keren

Comment: I tried your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C4HmP/). Works fine.

Comment: I missed some of the relevant css, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/kerenyaniv/qAFB5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Got it.
It was some problem in .row:after class.
Here is working version:

```
.row:after{content:"\0020";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;overflow:hidden;}
```

This code copied from blueprint css framework.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hrxet/1/) is all code.